# How to limit CPU numbers in Docker Client API?

Tags: python, r, docker, dockerpy

I have a script using `docker` python library or [Docker Client API](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/1.8.0/api/#containers). I would like to limit each docker container to use only 10cpus (total 30cpus in the instance), but I couldn't find the solution to achieve that.

I know in docker, there is `--cpus` flag, but `docker` only has `cpu_shares (int): CPU shares (relative weight)` parameter to use. Does everyone have experience in setting the limit on cpu usage using `docker`?

```py
import docker
client = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
container = client.containers.run(my_docker_image, mem_limit=30G)
```

Edits:

I tried `nano_cpus` as what [here](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/1920) suggests, like `client.containers.run(my_docker_image, nano_cpus=10000000000)` to set 10CPUS. When I inspectED the container, it did show "NanoCpus": 10000000000". However, if I run the R in the container and do `parallel::detectCores()`, it still shows 30, which I am confused. I also link R tag now.

Thank you!

Comment: Setting a CPU limit will keep the kernel from allocating your container more than that amount of processing time, but it won't make it look like there are fewer cores.  Your setup is probably correct and if you run it under load it shouldn't actually use more than 10 CPU worth.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks. I also noticed that just now, setting the `nano_cpus ` is managed by `cgroups`. If I use `parallelly` package in r, and run `parallelly::detectCores()`, it can give me the correct cpu values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `nana_cpus` works and you could use `parallelly::availableCores()` to detect cpus set by cgroup in r.

Answer (score 0):

All that I see about this is with operating systems. Is there a reason you can't just use these on system? Just asking for clarification here.

If you can use the cmd, then you can use this command:

```
sudo docker run -it --cpus=1.0 alpine:latest /bin/sh
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason is we already have many infra setup using the `docker-py`, so we prefer not to make huge big changes to just replace with CLI.

Comment: btw, I also tried to check cpus in your example container ( `docker run -it --cpus=1.0 alpine:latest /bin/sh`). It doesn't match the `--cpus` value.
/ # nproc --all
4

Comment: try this article: https://medium.com/codex/how-to-limit-cpu-and-memory-usage-in-docker-containers-a024b429f55e?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=A53D6E0F8473461AA587A7671B5386B9